# Hbase - scan.addFamily loop does not retrieve any result

Tags: java, hbase

I'm developing a set of queries in hbase and I need to read multiple column families. But when I add more than one column family my program doesn't retrieve any result.

The code to add the column families that I want to retrieve is:

```
Scan scan = new Scan(generateKey(start_key),generateKey(end_key));
    for (int i = 0; i <= families.length - 1; i++) {
        try {
            if(table.getTableDescriptor().hasFamily(Bytes.toBytes(families[i]))){
              scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes(families[i]));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the code to get the result and operate in a iterative loop with it:

```
while (res!=null && !res.isEmpty()){
                    byte [] column1_bytes = res.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(families[i]),Bytes.toBytes("COLUMN1"));
                    byte [] column2_bytes = res.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(families[i]),Bytes.toBytes("COLUMN2"));
                    String column1 = Bytes.toString(column1_bytes).toString();
                    String column2 = Bytes.toString(column2_bytes).toString();              
                    intervalTopTopic.put(column1, (long) Integer.parseInt(column2));
            res = rs.next();
        }
```